# php for loop freezes while looping

Tags: php, for-loop

When I tried to get variables while looping it just froze my screen and I got following error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/diligenceh/domains/diligencehelps.com/public_html/upload_lesson.php on line 16

The loop:

```
$lesson_count       = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['description_count']);
for($i = 1; $i <= $lesson_count; $i++)
{
    $image_url_ + $i = $_POST['image_url_'+ $i];
    echo $image_url_ + $i;
}
```

Comment: You sure you don't want to concatenate instead of doing math?

Comment: How is description_count field populated?

Comment: @raidenace It's a number 3-15 which is posted from input type='number'

Comment: is there a variable named `$image_url_`? because I think you trying to create a dynamic variable is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your code must be something like this:

```
$_POST['description_count'] = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['description_count'], -1, $lesson_count);

for($i = 1; $i <= $lesson_count; $i++) {
    echo  $_POST['image_url_'.$i];
}
```

pay atention in following:

1.- The 4th parameter in preg_replace() contain the number of replacements made.

2.- The function preg_replace return the original string with the changes. Read the manual here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

3.- I don't understand that what are you trying to do here:

```
$image_url_ + $i = $_POST['image_url_'+ $i];
```

you are using plus symbol (+) instead dot (.) to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is an endless loop

Try adding like `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`  //300 is seconds

Comment: How is that an endless loop? It may take some time, but endless?

Answer (score 0):

Create an array (was that your intention?)

```
$lesson_count = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['description_count']);
$image_url = array();

for($i = 1; $i <= $lesson_count; $i++) {
    $image_url[$i] = $_POST['image_url_'+ $i];
    echo $image_url[$i]; 
}
```

Also, are you sure `$lesson_count` is an integer larger than zero? I suspect not, since it is user input. You could try to force it into an integer with

```
$lesson_count = (int) preg_replace(...);
```

Comment: Sidenote: That should *probably* read as `$image_url_ = array();` and `echo $image_url_[$i];` since OP's using `$image_url_` using an underscore as a form of seperator.

Comment: Wait, scratch that, I see what you did. `$_POST['image_url_'+ $i]`

Answer (score 0):

Update your php.ini file, where you can increase execution time.
update `max_execution_time`
which is by default 30

increase your execution time there. for e.g. `max_execution_time = 100`